# I am trying to get this file to show Author before the CSV which is the "," only the first name shows

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the input
#Clive Cussler,Ghost Ship,9780399167315
#Clive Cussler,Bootlegger,9780399167295
#James Patterson,Invisible,9780316405345
#James Patterson,Gone for Now,9781455515845
#James Rollins,Map of Bones,9780062017855
#Michael Connely,Lincoln Lawyer,9781455516345
#David Baldacci,The Escape,9781478984345
set INPUT=0

set IFS=,

    

echo 'how do you want to sort the file?'
echo '1 for Author'
echo '2 for Title'
echo '3 ISBN'
read -r INPUT

case $INPUT in

        1) sort -t "," -k 1 project2.input > Proj2.sorted;
           outfile=project2.author.out;;

        2) sort -t, -k  project2.input > Proj2.sorted;
           outfile=project2.title.out;;


        3) sort -t, -k  project2.input > Proj2.sorted;
           outfile=project2.isbn.out;;

        *) echo 'invaled not 1-3'; exit;;

esac

# Setting up echo and header information here.
echo "******************************************" > "$outfile"
echo "* CIS 129 Project 2                      *" >> "$outfile"
echo "*          6/19/2021                     *" >> "$outfile"
echo "******************************************" >> "$outfile"



while read -r author title isbn
do
       echo $author

done < Proj2.sorted
```

Comment: thanks for the edit.

Comment: Please read: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The bash shell's `set` command is not the one you want in this context - it is used for setting the value of shell *options* and *positional parameters*.

Specifically, the command `set INPUT=0` sets the value of the shell's first positional parameter, `$1`, to `INPUT=0`. Then `set IFS=,` replaces it with `IFS=,`. The correct assignments would simply be `INPUT=0` and `IFS=,` respectively.

HOWEVER, the only place that the value of `IFS` appears to be significant is in your `read` command - and there you can set it locally i.e.

```
while IFS=, read -r author title isbn
```

so you don't need to set `IFS=,` elsewhere. You should also get into the habit of quoting variable expansions. So

```
while IFS=, read -r author title isbn
do
       echo "$author"

done < Proj2.sorted
```